# How to reverse the Bootstrap column dynamically?

Tags: php, html

I am using Bootstrap 5 on my website. I have min 4 products and its displaying on my page. Below is the view source of the code:

```
 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--some content here--></div>
 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--images--></div>

 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--some content here--></div>
 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--images--></div>

 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--some content here--></div>
 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--images--></div>

 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--some content here--></div>
 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--images--></div>
```

My expectation is, I have to reverse odd number of rows like below output

```
A | B
B | A
A | B
B | A

<div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--some content here--></div>
 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--images--></div>

 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--images--></div>
 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--some content here--></div>
 

 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--some content here--></div>
 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--images--></div>

 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--images--></div>
 <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><!--some content here--></div>
```

I am using below code.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php 
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                ?>
   <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <!--some content here-->
   </div>
   <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <!--images-->
   </div>

 <?php
    endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Introduce a counter variable and count up on each iteration and reverse the order if the counter variable is even.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found my answer, I don't know it is a best answer or not but it's solved my issue.

What I did, I added parent class called `products` and added `row` inside while loop and i added some css

```
.products .row:nth-child(even) {flex-direction: row-reverse !important;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="products">
    <?php 
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                ?>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <!--some content here-->
   </div>
   <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <!--images-->
   </div>
</div>

 <?php
    endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
    ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You can simply use `.row:nth-child(even) {flex-direction: row-reverse !important;}` in your template css.

Second way, just use a simple counter variable in your php code. In the below code snippet `$post_counter` will be initially 0 and for next post it will be 1 and again 0, continuously. And using a simple conditional statement we can display just the way we want.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $post_counter = 0;
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            if($post_counter == 0){ ?>
                <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <!--some content here-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <!--images-->
                </div>
            <?php $post_counter++; }else{ $post_counter = 0; ?>
                <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <!--images-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <!--some content here-->
                </div>
            <?php }
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    ?>
</div>
```